# Glide gif doesnt play

Tags: android, android-glide

I want to load a gif into an imageview, it is displayed but doesn't start playing. I use this code:

```
Glide.with(context)
             .load("https://media.giphy.com/media/7rj2ZgttvgomY/giphy.gif")
             .into(imageView)
```

I've also tried adding `.asGif()` but in that case image is not displayed at all. I'm using glide 3.8.0

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had set the imageview dimensions to **match_parent** and specifying it in dp did it for me.

Not sure why exactly match_parent doesn't work in a dialog, playing GIFs, probably something to do with the scaling, if this is the case then using **scaleType:fitXY** should work too

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
Glide.with(context)
    .load(imageUrl)
    .asGif()
    .placeholder(R.drawable.loading2)
    .crossFade()
    .into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try

```
Glide  
    .with(context)
    .load(gifUrl)
    .asGif()
    .error(R.drawable.full_cake)
    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)`
    .into(imageViewGif);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your gif your to **`https://i.giphy.com/media/7rj2ZgttvgomY/giphy.webp`**

```
Glide.with(context)
.load("https://i.giphy.com/media/7rj2ZgttvgomY/giphy.webp")
.asGif().into(imageView);
```

Also you can try [GIFView](https://github.com/Gavras/GIFView)

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to : https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1059

If you don't find it, you can change the lastest version of Gline

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.2.0'
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.2.0'
}
```

I hope you can find solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code. You could check if you have `Internet` permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Your internet speed might be slow and `Glide` might be taking too much time to load so by that time you could add a placeholder image using :

```
.placeholder(android.R.color.holo_green_dark)
```

Or you could add `Listner` to the `Request` using

```
  .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        return false;
                    }
                })
```

And see what is the `Exception`.

Comment: there is no exception

Comment: Is `onResourceReady` is getting called ?